# Haskell explicit recursion vs `iterate`

Tags: performance, loops, haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization

While writing a function using `iterate` in Haskell, I found that an equivalent version with explicit recursion seemed noticeably faster - even though I believed that explicit recursion ought to be frowned upon in Haskell.

Similarly, I expected GHC to be able to inline/optimise list combinators appropriately so that the resulting machine code is at least similarly performing to the explicit recursion.

Here's a (different) example, which also displays the slowdown I observed.

`steps m n` and its variant `steps'` compute the number of Collatz steps `n` takes to reach 1, giving up after `m` attempts.

`steps` uses explicit recursion while `steps'` uses list functions.

```
import Data.List (elemIndex)
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.DeepSeq (rnf)

collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n
  | even n    = n `quot` 2
  | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

steps :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
steps m = go 0
  where go k n
          | n == 1    = Just k
          | k == m    = Nothing
          | otherwise = go (k+1) (collatz n)

steps' :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
steps' m = elemIndex 1 . take m . iterate collatz

main :: IO ()
main = evaluate $ rnf $ map (steps 800) $ [1..10^7]
```

I tested these by evaluating for all values up to `10^7`, each giving up after `800` steps. On my machine (compiled with `ghc -O2`), explicit recursion took just under 4 seconds (`3.899s`) but list combinators took about 5 times longer (`19.922s`).

Why is explicit recursion so much better in this case, and is there a way of writing this without explicit recursion while preserving performance?

Comment: Have you considered checking whether your expectation about what GHC can do is correct? If it isn't, your `iterate` version would be generating, matching and collecting billions of elements, which would go a long way towards explaining the difference.

Comment: @thatotherguy Ultimately, I'm fairly sure my expectations about GHC are too high, but I'm fairly sure Haskell's laziness prevents billions of unnecessary elements being generated in `iterate` before any are consumed.

Comment: It's fair to assume each `iterate` would stop after generating no more than 800, but 800*10^7 is still billions.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how that justifies a difference though, since both versions have to make the same number of calculations

Comment: I'm getting 25s vs 53s for these two implementations. `./foo +RTS -s` shows that the fast version has `1,200,041,152 bytes allocated on the heap` vs `151,781,624,928 bytes` for the slow one, which does indicate that lists are being generated and searched. Number of arithmetic calculations is often not a good measure of workload due to how cheap they are compared to memory access or branch misprediction or such that CS analysis often considers free

Comment: Yes, I get similar values for allocation. Ah, I see how number of calculations may not reflect workload. My frustration is more that my understanding of GHC was that it is better at working with implicit recursion, and produces more efficient code when built-in functions are used instead of hand-rolled recursion.

Comment: When I add a `trace` inside `collatz`, both versions print exactly the same trace and take roughly the same amount of time. I don't understand why this would make such a difference ...

Comment: My suspicion is that values are being allocated in the lists version, but the explicit version is compiled into a tighter loop in machine code yet I don't see why GHC makes this distinction.

Comment: I'd expect you're seeing GHC is only managing to fully unbox the first example, because it's a simpler structure. Loop fusion isn't magic unfortunately.

Comment: @Veedrac This would make sense, is there any nice way I can demonstrate/see this without intuiting it?

Comment: @B.Mehta I believe you should look at the Core output; unboxing is denoted with `#`s. https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/GHC#Looking_at_the_Core

Comment: Those allocation numbers suggest to me that the list version isn't fusing the allocations away. That doesn't really surprise me, to be honest. Not sure `elemIndex` was ever written to participate in fusion. Regarding your tracing versions taking equal time - they're probably just both being dominated by the time taken to write to stdout, which is really quite slow.

Comment: I am not an expert on GHC but I think `elemIndex` is been evaluating lazily, that is: `GHC` is not waiting to `take` to finish. So for every call of `iterate` you check if `take m` can be applied and if `elemIndex 1` can be apply so that makes code slower. You can check my point executing this lines: `elemIndex 10 $ take 100000000000 $ map (+1) [1..]` and `elemIndex 100000000 $ take 100000000000 $ map (+1) [1..]`.

Comment: @LuisMorillo sure, but that's actually a good thing. If it did wait for `take` to finish then it would have to build up the entire big list in memory. Making this unnecessary is one of the main selling points of laziness. Just, it doesn't seem to work properly in this case.

Comment: @Carl Then I guess my question becomes, why isn't `findIndices` (which `elemIndex` is written in terms of) written to participate in fusion - surely it can be implemented as a zip, filter then map which can all be fused.

Comment: Hmm.  I traced the actual implementations GHC uses.  Everything in there should in fact be in terms of `foldr` and `build`.

Comment: @Carl Right, I don't fully understand the implementation of `findIndices` but it does look like it has fusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Updated:* I submitted [Trac 15426](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15426) for this bug.

The problem disappears if you copy the definitions of `elemIndex` and `findIndex` into your module:

```
import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Control.DeepSeq (rnf)

import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Data.List (findIndices)

elemIndex       :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
elemIndex x     = findIndex (x==)

findIndex       :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int
findIndex p     = listToMaybe . findIndices p

collatz :: Int -> Int
collatz n
  | even n    = n `quot` 2
  | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

steps' :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
steps' m = elemIndex 1 . take m . iterate collatz

main :: IO ()
main = evaluate $ rnf $ map (steps' 800) $ [1..10^7]
```

The problem *seems* to be that these must be inlinable for GHC to get the fusion right.  Unfortunately, neither of them is marked inlinable in `Data.OldList`.

The change to allow `findIndex` to participate in fusion is relatively recent (see [Trac 14387](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14387)) where `listToMaybe` was reimplemented as a `foldr`.  So, it probably hasn't seen a lot of testing yet.

Comment: It's so rare to see these sorts of questions uncover deficiencies in the language itself. I feel like I've glimpsed something under the water of Loch Ness!

Comment: Wow! I expected there was a deficiency in my understanding of fusion for `iterate`, rather than a missed inlinable.

Comment: @AdamSmith but this is not a deficiency in the language, it is merely a deficiency in GHC, a particular Haskell compiler.

Comment: @Cactus nitpicks :) But you're right, GHC /= Haskell, even if it's easy to see why someone might think it is.